# Rules of thumb for separating parts of a web application

Tags: php, ajax, web-applications

I am new to the world of web programming, have come up with some rules of thumb for the design of my first project. Do these sound like reasonable rules to go by, or should my code for various aspects of the project be more or less mixed together, or organized differently for some reason? Of the two books I've read relating to web programming (one on HTML & CSS, the other on PHP & MySQL), neither has clearly addressed this. Any opinions from experienced web developers will be greatly appreciated!

Rules of thumb:

1. For relatively static content, use PHP to generate pages (i.e., fill in a news story) so HTML and PHP are mixed just a little here.
2. For dynamic features, implement as an XML/plain text API so the PHP back end is not mixed in with any presentation logic (i.e., a server side API/service is implemented with no knowledge of presentation in it, then an AJAX client is developed and presented to the user)
3. Determine how to break up AJAX client into different pages based on desire for user to be able to bookmark a page and navigate with browser.

Comment: everyone has their own oppinion. if you are an OO programmer, you may see the MVC design pattern recommended everywhere. this separates routing, business logic, and display and seems to work fairly well for many. you may also want to look into free frameworks that already impliment this design pattern (Zend Framework, CodeIgniter, Kohana). you may want to look into books about design patterns, and agile developement, as they help keep your code malleable.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for web applications. You don't need to resort to XML/plain text to separate presentation from logic. Using a PHP framework such as [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org) or [Cake](http://www.cakephp.org) may help.

It may be best to develop a web application using HTML first and then sprinkle some AJAX on top so your application has a fallback if AJAX fails - e.g. mobile devices.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Looks like the MVC pattern is the way to go here. I checked out the first section of the CakePHP documentation. It looks like, with the MVC model, I can generate pages with filled in content server side, and easily optimize the user experience by making another view that generates XML/plaintext (depending on complexity of data) to be processed and inserted AJAX style. Are you suggesting having an HTML only fallback site without the AJAX optimizations for mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate the [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which is a great way to organize applications and separate the controller logic from the presentation logic.

Some popular PHP MVC frameworks include:

- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)

A more "difficult" framework (but the one I like the best), is [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)

I would recommend starting with one of the first two.

Comment: I would recommend CodeIgniter over CakePHP, it's faster, smaller, and simpler.

Comment: @timw4mail CodeIgniter sounds good (less "automagic", less configuration, and perhaps faster). I notice on the CodeIgniter site they have an "is CodeIgniter right for me?" list that has "You are not interested in large-scale monolithic libraries like PEAR." I don't understand what using PEAR has to do with selecting a framework...

Comment: A framework like CodeIgniter comes with a bunch of libraries, they're basically saying "Our libraries are better than PEAR libraries!" which I don't really have an opinion on. (Never used CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 1):

Small, static sites: HTML only, or PHP with included header and footer, and common functions.

More complex: MVC framework that separates Views (templates) , Models (Database calls and data manipulation), and Controllers (Page routing)

AJAX: MVC framework on the backend, special page routes for getting page data (check for the right headers), history.pushState w/ hashbang backup for partial page loads. Depending on the complexity, perhaps having client-side templating.

Comment: I should have initially noted that I've mainly been working on PHP, HTML, and CSS and have just started looking at JavaScipt/AJAX and I'm trying to figure out how all the pieces fit together nicely. Looks like looking into an MVC framework is the next step.  For your final point, am I correct in understanding that history.pushState/hashbang URLs are a way to allow the user to navigate as usual and bookmark while using an AJAX driven page?  Also, any suggestions as to where to look for client side templating information? Sounds like that's the next thing to learn after a MVC framework. Thanks!

Comment: I would only resort to client-side templating if you have extremely complex layout structure, and need to replace parts of very complex pages. For the most part, sending HTML to replace different sections of the page is usually sufficient.

Comment: The history API allows you to change the page url, and keep the back button working with partial page loads. It allows you to use the same urls with and without javascript. Hashbang urls are a hack that allows you to have a url that works with the back button, but is useless without Javascript. Currently Internet Explorer and Opera don't support the history API.